# Generic object to generic object with Automapper

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, automapper

I have a problem to copy generic object to generic object

```
public class Customer
{
    public int CustomerId { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Quote> Quotes { get; set; }
}
```

I use this generic class to copy object to object :

```
public static class GenericAutomapper
{
    public static void PropertyMap<T, U>(T source, U destination)
        where T : class, new()
        where U : class, new()
    {
        Mapper.CreateMap(typeof(T), typeof(U));
        Mapper.Map<T, U>(source); //crash here
    }
}
```

When I get a customer (using EF 6.1.2) and use this method, I get on error on the "crash here" line. The Quotes collection look like :
*'((System.Data.Entity.DynamicProxies.Customer_AC635AD71AC95634EF9694FDC434135B488FD116F3C2B6A287846A7886521F3F)source).Quotes'*

I don't have any problem when I include this : `.Include(x => x.Quotes)` in my query, normal the collection is loaded.

Is there a way to manage the "not loaded" collection ?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

You need to either turn off lazy loading or execute the query before mapping; the call to .Include() helps with this or you need to .ToList() (or something similar) before applying the mapping.

Comment: This class must stay generic and of course nothing specific about a class.

Comment: The mapping class will stay specific, but the issue is that you're trying to map a dynamic proxy class which isn't a good idea. You need to execute the query (which will be none generic as I expect you'll be working on specific DBSet<>s) and then call the AutoMapper mapping function. This will give you concrete types and should allow the map to function. That is best guess with the limited information provided.